# Logentries Docker container will not start

Tags: docker, rancher, logentries

I have just added the [Logentries](https://docs.logentries.com/docs/docker-logentries-container/) [Docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/logentries/docker-logentries/) container, to a [Rancher](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v1.6/en/) setup. We have another set of LE Docker containers running already just fine. However, this new container will not start – the logs say:

```
events.js:85
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
Error: connect ENOENT
  at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
  at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1012:19)
```

I am not familiar enough with Logentries' Docker-based setup to understand what is going on here.

It looks like it is failing to connect to something, but what? How can I try to find out?

Comment: Are you using the proxy?

Comment: No, we're not using a proxy, good thought.

Comment: I think I've solved this – I'm going to write up an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is linking `docker.sock` into the Logentries containers.

[Logentries' documentation](https://docs.logentries.com/docs/docker-logentries-container/) says you'll need a docker command something like this:

`docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock logentries/docker-logentries -t <token>`

But in Rancher you don't enter the raw Docker command, you have to [attach the volume when creating the service](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v1.6/en/cattle/volumes/), equivalent to the `-v /var...` option in the docker command.

[image: Rancher widget for entering a volume]